# Не записывается текст в label c#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, label

Нужно из файла записать текст в label. Проблема: записывается только часть первой строки (текста много)

Так осуществляю запись:

```
private void Biography_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormShortInfo frmShInfo = this.Owner as FormShortInfo;
        string surname = frmShInfo.textBox1.Text;
        string bioPath = "bio/" + surname + ".txt";
        labelBio.Text = File.ReadAllText(bioPath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
    }
```

Comment: А какое форматирование стоит у строки? Может у вас отображается только первая строка. Нужно настроить на отображение нескольких строк

Comment: @AlexsandrTer а где это делается?

Comment: Я добавил ответ, смотрите ниже

Comment: @AlexsandrTer отображается на 3 буквы больше, думаю что проблема в переносе строк (оно выходит за окно лабела) но заметил что форма не увеличивается в размерах для проверки, попробую сначала это исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать textbox

```
var myLabel = new TextBox
                    {
                        Text = "xxx xxx xxx",
                        WordWrap = true,
                        AutoSize = false,
                        Enabled = false,
                        Size = new Size(60, 30),
                        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
                        Multiline =  true,
                        BackColor =  container.BackColor
                    };
```

или

Добавить label на панель

Добавить обработчик события

```
private void Panel2_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.MaximumSize = new Size((sender as Control).ClientSize.Width - label1.Left, 10000);
}
```

установить Auto-Size for the label to true

Установить Dock for the label to Fill